# Is there a way that I could assign a value to a variable at the same time as checking if it's null or not?

Tags: c#

I currently have this code:

```
    private static void IsEntryWidthChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if ((bindable as SingleEntryGrid)._column3 != null)
            (bindable as SingleEntryGrid)._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
    }
```

Is here a way that I could assign (bindable as SingleEntryGrid) to a variable while at the same time checking it is not null and then use that for the next line such that the next line became:

```
    singleEntryGrid._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `var col = (bindable as SingleEntryGrid)._column3; if (col != null) col.Width = (double)newValue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could use `??=` to supply a new object if the existing is null:

```
((bindable as SingleEntryGrid)._column3 ??= new ColumnThing()).Width = newValue;
```

Replace `ColumnThing` with the type `_column3` has. You can set more properties with `{ X = Y }` initializer after the `()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```cs
if ((bindable is SingleEntryGrid singleEntryGrid) && singleEntryGrid._column3 != null)
    singleEntryGrid._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achievable through [`Pattern matching with the **switch** statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement) & [`The case statement and the when clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) as below.

```
switch (bindable)
{
    case SingleEntryGrid singleEntryGrid when singleEntryGrid?._column3 != null:
        singleEntryGrid._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
        break;
}
```

---

**P.S** Rather than doing it with `switch case` I would rather add one more line to the code to assign object first and then check the condition.

```
var singleEntryGrid = (bindable as SingleEntryGrid);
if (singleEntryGrid?._column3 != null)
    singleEntryGrid._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IsEntryWidthChanged` as extension method for your `singleEntryGrid`

```
      public static void IsEntryWidthChanged(this BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (bindable._column3 != null)
                bindable._column3.Width = (double)newValue;
            else
                bindable._column3.Width = DEFAULT_Width_VALUE;
        }
```

usage:

```
singleEntryGrid.IsEntryWidthChanged(oldValue,newValue);
```